# How to get the left chain of points of a polygon?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

I am trying to get the left polygonal chain given a set of consecutive points. (NOTE: edges are non-intersecting.)

[image]

**Image 1.** Sample polygon and its bound.

What I did was:

1. Get the `minY`, `maxY` and `minX`. (Bound.)
2. Find the point that contains `minY` (or `maxY`) then save it as the first point.
3. Save any points until point with `minY` or `maxY` is found while checking for  point with `minX`.
4. If the same Y is found first, save it as the new first point and repeat from #3.
5. If other Y is found first and the saved points has `minX`, this is the chain. Otherwise, save as the new first point and repeat from #3.

[image]

**Image 2.** The left chain of points.

But using this steps might give wrong result for some polygon, like this:

[image]

Since one point is (`minX`, `maxY`), either of the side will be returned.

**EDIT:**
With the idea of the left-bottom- and left-top-most points, here is the current code that I am using:

Get the min (left-bottom-most) and max (left-top-most) point.

```
std::vector<Coord> ret;
size_t i = 0;
Coord minCoord = poly[i];
Coord maxCoord = poly[i];
size_t minIdx = -1;
size_t maxIdx = -1;
size_t cnt = poly.size();
i++;
for (; i < cnt; i++)
{
    Coord c = poly[i];
    if (c.y < minCoord.y)   // new bottom
    {
        minCoord = c;
        minIdx = i;
    }
    else if (c.y == minCoord.y) // same bottom
    {
        if (c.x < minCoord.x)   // left most
        {
            minCoord = c;
            minIdx = i;
        }
    }
    if (c.y > maxCoord.y)   // new top
    {
        maxCoord = c;
        maxIdx = i;
    }
    else if (c.y == maxCoord.y) // same top
    {
        if (c.x < maxCoord.x)   // left most
        {
            maxCoord = c;
            maxIdx = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Get the points connected to the max point.

```
i = maxIdx;
Coord mid = poly[i];
Coord ray1 = poly[(i + cnt - 1) % cnt];
Coord ray2 = poly[(i + 1) % cnt];
```

Get which has smallest angle. This will be the path we will follow.

```
double rad1 = Pts2Rad(mid, ray1);
double rad2 = Pts2Rad(mid, ray2);
int step = 1;
if (rad1 < rad2)
    step = cnt - 1;
```

Save the points.

```
while (i != minIdx)
{
    ret.push_back(poly[i]);
    i = (i + step) % cnt;
}
ret.push_back(poly[minIdx]);
```

Comment: ok, so you discovered that there's no good definition of what "left" means for arbitrary polygons. What is your question?

Comment: By now you should know this, but please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you only have the vertices (and not the connectivity), then multiple polygons are possible.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth the vertices are consecutive

Comment: Looks like you need to work out what you're expecting to get in your own examples before you can work out an algorithm to return it

Comment: Your problem is not well posed. First setup a clean definition of what you mean by "left chain of points". Then you can setup an algorithm that solves the problem based on that definition.

Comment: I suppose this could be defined as: (1) find leftmost point at maxY, (2) find leftmost point at minY, (3) of the two paths between them, pick the one that has no other points to its left.  That ought to be achievable by starting from (1), and picking whichever neighbour is the furthest left.

Comment: An "anticlockwise order" is difficult to define for whole polygons, but easy for two consecutive edges. Thus you can count the number of such pairs of consecutive edges which either give an anticlockwise or clockwise order; the category with the most edges gives the order of the polygon. You can also weight this count with e.g. the product of the edge lengths.

Answer (score 0):

To be specific, I am assuming that no vertex is duplicated and define the "left chain" as the sequence of vertices from the original polygon loop that goes from the leftmost vertex in the top side of the bounding box, to the leftmost vertex in the bottom side of the bounding box. [In case the top and bottom sides coincide, these two vertices also coincide; I leave it to you what to return in this case.]

To obtain these, you can scan all vertices and keep the left-topmost so far and left-bottommost so far. Then compare to the next vertex. If above the left-topmost, becomes the new lef-topmost. If at the same level and to the left, becomes the new left-topmost. Similarly for the left-bottommost.